# I was going through a textbook and came across this expression.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How is this transition possible:
$$e^u = \tan(\pi/4 + \theta/2)     \tag{given}$$
$${\cfrac{e^{u/2}}{e^{-u/2}}} =\cfrac{1+\tan(\theta/2)}{1-\tan(\theta/2)} $$

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{1+ \tan\theta/2}{1- \tan\theta/2}?$$

Comment: are you sure its $\tan(\frac\theta2)$ because im getting $\tan(\theta)$?

Comment: @pranavB23 sorry, actually i made mistake while writing that given part , it was $\theta/2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:
$$\frac{e^\frac{u}{2}}{e^\frac{-u}{2}}=e^u$$
and by usual [trigonometry formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities):
$$\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{4}+\theta \right)=\frac{\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)+\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{4}\right) \tan(\theta)}$$
as $\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)=1$ you obtain:
$$\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{4}+\theta \right)=\frac{1+\tan(\theta)}{1- \tan(\theta)}$$

Comment: sorry, it was $\theta/2$ in given expression, anyways I got your point, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$e^u=\tan(\frac\pi4+\frac\theta2) = \frac{1+\tan(\frac\theta2)}{1-\tan(\frac\theta2)}$

$e^u =\dfrac{1+\tan(\frac\theta2)}{1-\tan(\frac\theta2)}$

$e^{\frac u2+\frac u2} = \dfrac{1+\tan(\frac\theta2)}{1-\tan(\frac\theta2)}$

$\dfrac{e^{\frac u2}}{e^{-\frac u2}} =\dfrac{1+\tan(\frac\theta2)}{1-\tan(\frac\theta2)} $